# Bash scripting with IFS

Tags: bash, ifs

I need in Bash with IFS=‘,’

./test.sh Mike,Texas Nik,Toronto Lucas,Iowa

Hello Mike

You are from Texas

Hello Nik

You are from Toronto

Hello Lucas

You are from Iowa

```
#!/bin/bash
    IFS=',' read -r -a array <<< "$string"


    for index in "${!array[@]}"
    do
            echo Hello "$index ${array[index]}"
            echo You are from "$index ${array[index]}"
    done
```

Comment: Please, read [how to create a Minimum Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: you should elaborate what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: and your Q should include your best attempt to solve your problem. We'll help you fix it, but we don't want to do it for you. Good luck.

Comment: Excuse me, you are absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to modify `IFS` (the *Internal Field Separator*), you need *parameter expansion with substring removal*, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in "$@"; do
    printf "Hello %s\nYou are from %s\n" "${i%,*}" "${i#*,}"
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./test.sh Mike,Texas Nik,Toronto Lucas,Iowa
Hello Mike
You are from Texas
Hello Nik
You are from Toronto
Hello Lucas
You are from Iowa
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I loved your answer, it's very ingenious.

What I do not understand is ... (%, *) and (# *,)

Can you explain it to me?

Thank you again

Comment: It's called *parameter expansion with substring removal*. `${var#*,}` trims the string in `var` from the LEFT up to and including the **1st** comma, `${var%,*}` does the same thing from the RIGHT (**note** the location of the `'*'` wildcard). You can use `${var##*,}` to trim from the LEFT up to and including the **last** comma, and the same thing from the RIGHT with `${var%%,*}`. It is explained under the heading **Parameter Expansion** in `man bash`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over arguments using just `for argument` - this will populate the variable named `argument` with the space separated arguments one at a time. Then you can read the comma-separated values. For example:

```
set -- Mike,Texas Nik,Toronto Lucas,Iowa # For testing purposes
for argument
do
    IFS=, read name state <<< "$parameter"
    echo "Hello ${name}"
    echo "You are from ${state}"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on what I see, here is my suggestion:

```
for i in $* ; do

     name=$(echo $i | awk -F, '{print $1}' )
     wherefrom=$(echo $i | awk -F, '{print $2'})

     echo Hello $name, you are from $wherefrom
done
```

Comment: Why two `awk`s?  `echo $i | awk -F, '{print "Hello",$1,"you are from " $2}'`.  By the way, `for i` will suffice (you don't need the `in $*`).

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer has been very successful.

Comment: cdarke - Your solution and mine both work. Yours is more concise and thus for the given problem is probably better.  My solution extracts the name and destination into variables, which might be useful in some more complex context.